# Profiling only certain parts/classes of a Java application

Tags: java, performance, profiling

I'm writing a java application that reads input, populates data structures, and then does some computations on them.  I want to optimize the final computation part, because with real, large inputs it dominates execution time.  Profiling the whole application with giant inputs would take forever.  So, I load a moderate-sized input for performance testing, but then input and preprocessing time dominates the profile.

How can I profile just the part of a java application I care about?  Is there a way to say "only profile these two classes," or programmatically insert "start profiling here" directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to profile your code. I don't know about only profiling specific classes, but VisualVm can start watching programs that are already running. Also, if you are using Eclipse, there is a launcher that can be used to start and attach the profiler to your program when you start it from Eclipse.

**EDIT:**
I did some looking and the Profiler tab has a Settings check box. When you select this, it will show a text box where you can set up filters on what classes should be profiled for CPU usage.

Comment: Combined with a preset that saves my filters and a judiciously placed `Thread.sleep(5000)`, it gets the job done. :)  It's sad that that's the state of the art, though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have unit tests and you can construct a unit test or application which just does the portion you are interested in profiling.  This way you can performance tune this alone because its the only thing running.

Comment: Unit tests test correctness with very small inputs.  Even there the majority of the time is spent preprocessing.  In order to get meaningful performance numbers, I need to run with large inputs, which take time to load.  I can't test my algorithm without any data loaded.

Comment: How realistic does the data have to be?  Often generated data is more light weight and can give you realistic performance results.

Comment: If you have to have the real data, you can have the program stop before running you algo, start profiling and let the program continue.  This way you will only be profiling what is run from that point.

Answer (score 0):

As for profiling only selected classes, most profilers allow to set up filters, so that only a couple of classes are instrumented.

In your case, it sound like you would also like to start and stop profiling when a particular method is called.

In [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), you can add a **method trigger** for the desired method and add 3 actions to the trigger:

- Start recording (with CPU selected)
- Wait for the current event to finish
- Stop recording (with CPU selected).

Have a look at [this screen cast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2010/03/offline-profiling-and-triggers.html) that shows how triggers are configured.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.